# Error Receiving broadcast Intent ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, batterylevel

I am trying to get battery information through the use of a broadcast receiver and store it in a database. I'd prefer to get it only when I specifically want it, but I am willing to keep a database of just running records of it. Anyways, The problem is my app crashes with this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED flg=0x60000010 (has extras) }
at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:765)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f04006b
at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:242)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3773)
at com.Eddiecubed44.drunk.buddy.Main$2.onReceive(Main.java:180)
at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:755)
```

And when i say crash, I mean crash and burn.  My phone restarts itself every time I run it with this code in it.
I've stepped through with the debugger and haven't caught the error.  I create the broadcast Receiver in my main activity class as so:

```
    BroadcastReceiver batteryReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            int temp = -1;
            TextView tempText;

            tempText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mybatttemptxt);
            temp = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE, -1);
            tempText.setText(R.string.temp + temp);
```

This is how im registering the Broadcast Receiver.

```
this.registerReceiver(this.batteryReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
```

I do this in my onStart Method.  The thing is, I can run my app if i replace this.batteryReceiver with null, but the app does nothing.  The receiver is not called or used anywhere else in this app.

If it matters heres what I'm using:
testing on rooted galaxy s3
app is using target lvl15 api min 11.

Comment: post your manifest permission

Comment: Concerning @HoanNguyen's comment: it's more likely that you're referencing an element in your layout incorrectly. But to know that, you'd need to post a bigger excerpt both of your logcat and the code itself.

Comment: My uses-permissions or my activity and intent-Filter and what not?

Comment: Your whole receiver code.

Comment: I don't register it in the manifest, just in the onStart Method.

Comment: Yes but your code for batteryReceiver has some error or you misses some permission.

Comment: It look like //post some info into textViews is where the error is.

Comment: Hi! StackOverflow is for programming questions, and you have not asked a question. Your stack trace shows you where your code has an issue, and you did not post that code, so it will be difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: Ive added some code in.  and I don't have any permissions related to the Battery receiver in my manifest.

Comment: The line 180 happens right on the 'temp = intent.putIntExtra('  line.

Comment: "The line 180 happens right on the 'temp = intent.putIntExtra(' line." -- no, it does not. The stack trace clearly shows that your error is coming from a call to `setText()`. Whether that is the `setText()` call in your abbreviated code listing or not, only you can determine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got an inexistent Resource in line 180 of your Main.java.

My guess is it's `R.string.temp` but since you haven't posted even the name of your file, it's just that: a guess.

And I just saw the trouble:

```
tempText.setText(R.string.temp + temp);
```

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28int%29) allows setting the text directly to a resid. However, by adding temp to that value, you altered it and are asking for an inexistent resource.

One way to correct it would be to:

```
String resourceTemp = context.getString(R.string.temp);
tempText.setText(resourceTemp + " " + temp);
```

Comment: So I'm assuming if I decide to write it as a single string and not use R.string.temp and include "script" instead.

Answer (score 1):

You add a resource id to temp and thus change the id, you should change to

```
tempText.setText(context.getString(R.string.temp) + temp);
```

Comment: holy stuff that I can't talk about here (i dont think) that made it all better.  Thanks.  I was not expecting it to be a elementary mistake like this.

Comment: @DigCamara I did not pay attention didn't I? Well, your answer is a plus anyway.